# Как выполнить http/get запрос с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, get

Есть запрос типа: smsc.ru/send.php?phone=7777777&message=textsms. Подскажите пожалуйста, как его выполнить с помощью чистого JS? Результатом запроса будет отправленное смс. Пробовал вот так

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Не работает.
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Возможно у вас в консоли браузера имеется какая-нибудь ошибка, которая может натолкнуть на решение.

Comment: Ошибка: Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Может быть из-за того, что я пишу в CodePen?

Comment: запрос то кросс-доменный видимо?

Comment: Да, вы правы, это кросс-доменный запрос. Этот же запрос легко выполняю на C#, и PHP, но вот в JS что-то не получается..

Comment: говорят асинхронным должен быть

Comment: C false на true поменять? Тоже не помогает..

Comment: чтобы на js он выполнился на той стороне должны быть выставлены соответствующие заголовки, разрешающие xhr запросы. Если там такового нет, то напишите на стороне вашего сервера (c#, php) скрипт который будет отправлять такой запрос, а из js обращайтесь к своему скрипту (прокси так сказать).

Comment: если вы просто поменяете на true, то результат из функции так не вернется, ибо сам запрос еще не будет завершен. смотрите винструментах браузера что происходит в сетевой активности, там будет виден этот запрос, и можно просмотреть его ответ.

Comment: вообще в [API указан другой URL](http://smsc.ru/api/) и параметры

Comment: По идее, раз это GET, то можно, например, просто создать невидимый iframe с нужным адресом. Или даже img (но тут я с ходу не уверен, не возникнет ли риска каких-либо побочных эффектов).

Comment: Запрос написал в качестве примера, сейчас пишется свой сервис.

Comment: кхм, то есть я тут доки по API этого сайта читаю, просто потому что вы что-то указали его в качестве примера, а вообще разрабатываете свой сервер, про который забыли упомянуть что ли?

Comment: Смотрите, не стоит зацикливаться на самом запросе и домене, который в нем используется. Я сразу написал, что меня интересует как его выполнить с помощью JS. Прощу прощения, если сбил вас с толку) Ваш предыдущий комментарий я уже пометил как полезный)

Comment: я до сих пор не понимаю, что вы тогда пытаетесь сделать. это эмуляция отправки запроса к вашему сервису? тогда где код серверной стороны? опишите задачу целиком, а не какие то обрывки, на которые не понятно с какой стороны смотреть.